# How to make this sql with query array_agg?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, array-agg

I want to make a query

```
select * from projects where user_id = 3;
```

and depending on it's result `r`, I need to make `n` queries, where `n` is the *length* `l` of `r`. eg:

```
| id | project_name | description | user_id |
| 1  | Project A    | lorem ipsu  | 3       |
| 4  | Project B    | lorem ipsu  | 3       |
```

`l => 2` *then*:

```
select * from images where project_id = 1;
select * from images where project_id = 4;
```

Ok, you can see where this is going if `l` is too big. Too many selects, too many access to the database. Is there a better way to achieve an end result like so:

```
| id | project_name | description | user_id | images           |
| 1  | Project A    | lorem ipsu  | 3       | {imgX,imgY,imgZ} |
| 4  | Project B    | lorem ipsu  | 3       | {imgA,imgB}      |
```

I heard about `array_agg` function on postgres. Maybe that's the answer? Anyways, these are my table descriptions:

```
                             Table "public.projects"
   Column    |           Type           |                           Modifiers                       
-------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                  | not null default     nextval('projects_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(255)   | 
 description | character varying(255)   | 
 user_id     | integer                  | 
 created_at  | timestamp with time zone | 
 updated_at  | timestamp with time zone | 

                                    Table "public.images"
   Column   |           Type           |                      Modifiers                      
------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('images_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying(255)   | 
 url        | character varying(255)   | 
 project_id | integer                  | 
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |
```

And thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_agg` is like any other aggregate function (count, sum), but returns an array instead of a scalar value. What you need can be achieved simply by joining and grouping the 2 tables.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.user_id, array_agg(i.name) images
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.id = i.project_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.description, p.user_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was easy to understand. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You want records from `projects` plus records in `image names as array` matching by `project_id` :

```
SELECT *
FROM   projects
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_agg(name) AS images FROM images WHERE project_id = projects.project_id) x ON true
WHERE user_id = '3'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8a66/1)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution for you is a sub-select. This comes closest to the individual `SELECT` statements that you mention earlier:

```
SELECT * FROM images
WHERE project_id IN (
  SELECT project_id FROM projects
  WHERE user_id = 3);
```